# Write a Generic Method that references static generic collections?

Tags: c#, generics, design-patterns, concurrency

I have to write a method that takes in as a parameter string,int,short,long,float, or double and then assigns a random value to that parameter and stores it in a static `ConcurrentDictionary`. Performance is a major constraint, so I don't want to go with a design that will sacrifice performance

Example:

```
public void StoreVal<T>(T val)
{
   //Check if the val is already in the respective dictionary

   //If not, then create a random value 

   //Store both values in the dictionary
}
```

I created a static ConcurrentDictionary for each of the datatypes that I'm expecting. The key issue I'm facing now is how do I reference correct collection type from within the generic method, without having to use a whole bunch of if/else statements?

UPDATE: I am using a ConcurrentDictionary because this method will be called by 8 threads (at least) and I have to ensure there is only one mapped value for passed parameter. Another constraint is that each data-type should have it's own mapping i.e. if 10 (int) -> 25 (int), then 10 (short) is not required to point to 25 (short) - that's why I created a separate ConcurrentDictionary for each datatype.

Comment: Is this an assignment, or do you have flexibility in how you implement?

Comment: @hatchet I've updated my question based on your response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If** performance is critical and **if** the set of possible input types limited and known, consider using functions overloading instead of a generic function :

```
public void StoreVal(int val) { // no if needed, you know which Dictionary to use }

public void StoreVal(float val) { // no if needed, you know which Dictionary to use }

public void StoreVal(double val) { // no if needed, you know which Dictionary to use }

// etc ...
```

Other solutions will necessary make use of branching, casts, or some form of boxing, which will in any case degrade your performances.

Comment: The "cost" of boxing is *super* low.  It's *very* unlikely that boxing, in a case like this, would case any noticeable performance problem.

Comment: I agree, but "super low" might be too much for some critical applications, I've personally seen it in production code. The OP did not mention the context anyway.

Comment: The odds of there not being other changes that would have radically more significant improvements on performance are very, very low.  If this change could actually result in a measurable difference, then there are almost certainly thousands of more suitable improvements in the program.  People *love* to bring up boxing as an example of an "expensive" operation that should constantly be optimized, but it's just *not that expensive* of an operation.  It involves only a handful of some of the most simple things that a processor can do, really.

Comment: I went ahead with this solution to keep the design simple and avoid any performance penalties whatsoever. Performance is a concern for me because this method will be called 2-3 Billion times!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply call `GetOrAdd` to add the value if it is not already there:

```
private ConcurrentDictionary<object, object> dictionary;
public void StoreVal<T>(T val)
{
    dictionary.GetOrAdd(val, _ => ComputeRandomValue());
}
```

Comment: does this treat an int=10 and short=10 as two separate keys?

Comment: @tunafish24 yes it does. They have different hash codes

Comment: @tunafish24 dcastro is correct, and even if they had the same has, their `equals` methods considers them different.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to create overloads for each of those types (int, long, short, float and double). They're all value types, and, as such, don't have any common ancestor.

This is why many of the methods you find throughout the Base Class Library offer these overloads.

Your method's signature, as it stands, will accept *any* kind of parameter,  even though it can only handle a small subset of them. This breaks the [*principle of least surprise*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment).

Comment: Overloading is my first choice at the moment. I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution that doesn't sacrifice performance.